# PHP Password Hash Verifies on Hash Creation but Fails Verification with MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, apache, passwords, php-password-hash

I am building a dashboard system, with Apache running on a raspberry pi, and pre-generating a password and its hash for all new users.

The line I used to do this is `password_hash('Password1@', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`.

Users are shown a password reset window when they first log in. I am able to successfully use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` after the users click submit on this password reset page.

The first login works just fine but on any login attempt after logging out results in the `password_verify()` failing.

**What I Have Checked/Tried**

- Set the password attribute in the database to `varchar(255)`.
- A single user row *is* retrieved and I can return data from it.
- `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` and `PASSWORD_ARGON2ID` both do this.

**Things I Know**

- Database is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.
- The new password that users set are successfully pushed to the database.

  - I have added an `if` statement to check that the new hash can be verified and it can be.
- Hash string matches what comes back in the `SELECT`, as it should.
- I used the functions below on other projects, with PHP 7. This project is on PHP 8. (Could this be the issue?)

**Password Reset Function**

```
public function firstLoginUpdatePassword($username, $password, $confirm, $token)
{
    if ($password != $confirm)
    {
        header("Location: first-login?mismatch&token=" . $token);
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $newPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE Account SET Password=:password, isFirstLogin=FALSE, Token=:token WHERE Username=:username");
            $stmt->bindparam(":username", $username);
            $stmt->bindparam(":password", $newPassword);
            $stmt->bindparam(":token", $token);

            if ($stmt->execute())
            {
                header("Location: home");
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: first-login?error&token=" . $token);
                exit;
            }
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**Login Function**

```
public function Login($user, $pwd)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT Username, Password FROM Account WHERE Username=:username or Email=:username;");
        $stmt->bindparam(":username", $user);
        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            if (password_verify($pwd, $row['Password']))
            {
                try
                {
                    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE Account SET LastLogin=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE Username=:username;");
                    $stmt->bindparam(":username", $row['Username']);
                    if ($stmt->execute())
                    {
                        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['Username'];
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: login?error-other");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                catch (PDOException $ex)
                {
                    echo $ex->getMessage();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: login?error-credential");
                exit;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: login?error-login");
            exit;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything looks correct as far as the `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions. You're saying `if (password_verify($pwd, $row['Password']))` is returning FALSE? If so, the only thing I can think of is your query states `WHERE Username=:username or Email=:username` where everything else is only `WHERE Username=:username`. Since `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` only fetches the first entry, are there possibly two entries where the Email is the username and another record where Username is the username?

Comment: @MarshallC The `if` statement is returning false, correct. The login function allows a user to put their username or email address, hence the `WHERE` clause in that function. Everything else I have is set to update based on the username. Both attributes have `unique constraints` on them, and I don't run the `password_verify()` if more than one are returned (redundant check, now that I think about it, since I use `fetch_assoc`). I only have 2 records in the database for now. Very different username/email entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was somewhere in the file encoding. There was a mixture of encodings on my PHP files on the server. I re-encoded all files, recursively, to UTF-8 and the issue is gone now.